# Set display block JQuery Toggle as default / CSS positioning

Tags: jquery, css, html, toggle, positioning

This is my first time asking on this great website (that I've been learning from for a long time now). 
I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me with this:
Im working on this free html5 template called "Proximet".

On this [website](http://www.anariel.com/previewanarieldesign/Proximet/about.html):

1. I would like to know how could I make the toggles display block as default. 
   I tried adding the `style="display: block;` " but somehow I get `display:none;` as default. I would like all toggles open as default.
2. On the other hand, I would like to know how could I make the website to occupy the whole height of the browser window. I am on a 21 inch display, and the website doesnt seem to fulfill the whole height of the display. I would like the footer div placed on the very bottom of the website even if the content area is not filled with content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display will be set to "none" here:

```
// Toggle box
//##########################################
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.toggle-trigger').click(function() {
$(this).next().toggle('slow');
$(this).toggleClass("active");
return false;
}).next().hide();
});
```

Remove `.next().hide()` from the code and the elements will stay visible

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergio,
That worked perfectly fine!

Do you have any clue how could I fix the other issue ?

On the other hand, I would like to know how could I make the website to occupy the whole height of the browser window. I am on a 21 inch display, and the website doesnt seem to fulfill the whole height of the display. I would like the footer div placed on the very bottom of the website even if the content area is not filled with content.


Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you! That totally helped!